# Billing and shipping mismatch on some orders

Tags: commerce

I just recently getting billing and shipping mismatch on some orders which in turn  affects shipping rates. On below transaction shipping rates get billed for Afghanistan, but address details are for USA. Payments go through to Paypal which then need to be refunded due to the mismatch in Countries.

Having a look in the database I get 4 entries for this order, 2 shipping and two billing. [image: database screen]

At Home » Administration » Store » Orders >> order number I see this:

Billing information:
A. Customer
Afghanistan

Shipping information: 
A. Customer
1234 Wild Trail
Chocolate, OH 44233
United States

Any advise on how to trouble shoot this? Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Afghanistan is the default country in country select lists since it's first alphabetically. It appears to me that perhaps some part of your checkout form is causing a previously saved address to be overwritten. This is an infrequent but common issue when combining a variety of Ajax related features on a single checkout form. I'd begin debugging there to see if you can isolate the point at which stale address data is saved to the active billing profile accidentally.

Comment: Appreciate your response. Yes, it is a single checkout form and haven't had any issues previously. I am not familar with Ajax and have to do some digging.

Comment: I since changed the default country to USA, which should address the charges, as most costumers are US based.  I am thinking I have another possibly related issue to this where I get a payment via Paypal, but the order shows $0.00 and no customer info anywhere in the views or database. I have not been able to duplicate this behavior, but can occasionally get country, street ect. missing error message. Thanks for all you do.

Comment: Hmm, the extra detail makes me wonder if the connection to PayPal is incorrect and that it's recreating the billing profile based on an incomplete IPN response. What version of the module are you using?

Comment: PayPal Express Checkout Version: 7.x-2.4

Comment: after some testing I ended up using patch at https://www.drupal.org/node/2453499 and unchecking "copy billing info..." on the commerce/config/checkout/form/pane/customer_profile_billing . This resolves the errors and so far no missing address info on the billing page.